# Highlighted questions?

Tags: support, design, question-lists

Ok, I'm sure this a really lame question, and It's probably answered somewhere really obvious, but I can't find it. In stackoverflow, when I'm looking at a list of questions, why are some slightly highlighted, like in beige?

Comment: They are tagged with tag you added as favorite. :)

Comment: Thanks, yep, that's the question I was looking for!

Comment: When in doubt, search for relevant [meta-tag:faq] :)